# My dialler app is severely lagging

Tags: calls, phone-app, htc-sensation

I have a HTC Sensation running Android 4.0.3 (HTC Sense 3.6, 3.33.401.53).  Of late I've been having increasing problems with global lag, however this is really most noticeable on the dialler/phone app itself.  By more noticeable, I mean several times worse compared to anything else.

I can open the contacts menu in the dialler without difficulty and filter by name to get the number I want up, however I get no response when I click the name (aside from a green flash of it to indicate I've pressed sucessfully).  There's then a pause of I would say up to a minute in the worst cases before it actually dials.  Usually I've pressed it multiple times in the hope of it working, whereupon it calls the person multiple times and I end up with several calls to the same person 'on hold'.

Is there any known cause for this or *even better* any likely way to fix it?  I could do a factory reset if this doesn't get resolved as it makes the phone close to unusable.

The effect isn't really on answering calls, though there is a lag on that too (but not to anywhere near the degree).

Comment: You should really try factory reset.

Answer (score 2):

Having had no better suggestions I did try a factory reset and it seems to have resolved the problem entirely, indeed the phone 'feels' new.  Whilst it is annoying, it's been over a year since having the phone and it only took about an hour to factory reset and restore important files, so it's not the worst solution out there.

Comment: Factory reset is often the first thing you should try as it usually eliminates software as a possible factor, and in the end it often saves you time (much like a OS reinstall when it comes to Windows problems).

Answer (score 0):

This [advice from XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1766793&page=2) seems to be working for me.

> check if you have a process by name Media running in background using
>   Settings>Apps>Running Apps. Inside this process, if there is a service
>   running called MediaDBMigrationService then stop it immediately and it
>   will resolve the issue to large extent.

Comment: The process was indeed running when I checked just now (though with the status 'restarting') - I'll let you know if it improves the situation and accept your answer if so!